# Is order important when placing AngularJS formatter and parser functions into the $formatters and $parsers arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive 
(taken from the *Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS* book):

```
angular.module('unique-email-directive', [])

/**
 * A validation directive to ensure that the model contains a unique email address
 * @param  Users service to provide access to the server's user database
  */
.directive('uniqueEmail', ["Users", function (Users) {
  return {
    require:'ngModel',
    restrict:'A',
    link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var original;

      // If the model changes, store this since we assume it is the current value of the user's email
      // and we don't want to check the server if the user re-enters their original email
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
        original = modelValue;
        return modelValue;
      });

      // using push() here to run it as the last parser, after we are sure that other validators were run
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
        if (viewValue && viewValue !== original ) {
          Users.query({email:viewValue}, function (users) {
            if (users.length === 0) {
              ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('uniqueEmail', true);
            } else {
              ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('uniqueEmail', false);
            }
          });
          return viewValue;
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I need clarification about **whether it is important** to put the formatter function at the **beginning of the $formatters array** and the parser function at the **end of the $parsers array**.

If order is important, please kindly explain why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parsers and validators are run in order passing the returned value on to the next. you simply have to decide if you want your function to be run before all of the rest or after all the rest have had a chance to complete.

from angularjs docs:

> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control reads value from the DOM. Each function is called, in turn, passing the value through to the next. The last return value is used to populate the model. Used to sanitize / convert the value as well as validation. For validation, the parsers should update the validity state using $setValidity(), and return undefined for invalid values.

Comment: Thanks drex! Can you please provide the link for excerpt you quote?

Comment: sorry about that. it is here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers